# What regular expressions do I use to distinguish verbs in Spanish?

Tags: regex

I'm creating a program that will electronically conjugate verbs in Spanish from their infinitive forms.  For those of you who aren't super familiar with Spanish, a Spanish infinitive is the unconjugated form of a verb.  Here are a few examples of Spanish infinitives:

Hablar,
Comer,
Escribir,
Acostarse,
Comprometerse,
Vestirse

All infinitives in Spanish either end with "ar," "er," "ir," "arse," "erse," or "irse."  Each of these endings require an entirely different set of conjugations, thus I need to separate each one and handle them differently.

I want to know what regular expressions can do the following:

Find infinitive forms ending with "ar."

Find infinitive forms ending with "er."

Find infinitive forms ending with "ir."

Find infinitive forms ending with "arse."

Find infinitive forms ending with "erse."

Find infinitive forms ending with "irse."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been done before.

```
[aei]r(?:se)?$
```

Except that for real work, you might want to do the forms with non-reflexive attached pronouns too, like *decírmelo*.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of infinitive endings is wrong. Spanish infinitives can also end in *-ír* (e.g. *reír*). A (crude) regex to match this would be `[aeií]r$`. This assumes your text has already been [Unicode normalized to NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms).

Infinitives ending in *-arse* (etc.) are actually just regular verbs with the impersonal reflexive pronoun *se* appended as a [clitic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic). You don't need to deal with them in a conjugation program, because there's nothing in the conjugation specific to reflexive verbs (commonly written with *-se* in dictionaries); clitics can attach to any verb.

Another problem is that the Spanish infinitive doesn't preserve enough information to conjugate even regular verbs! In particular, if the stem as written ends in "u" or "i", you don't know whether it's phonetically /u/ (resp. /i/) versus /w/ (resp /j/). For example, "copiar" and "confiar" are both regular verbs, but from the infinitive you can't tell that the correct present-tense conjugations are

- copiar: *(yo) **co**pio* "I am copying"
- confiar: *(yo) con**fí**o* "I trust"

So if you are conjugating from the infinitive form, you *have* to resort to looking verbs up in a dictionary. (If you *also* have the 3sg or 3pl forms in the present indicative or subjunctive, that is usually enough.)